# Fitting data with a double Gaussian

Tags: python-3.x, gaussian

I am attempting to fit some data with a double Gaussian profile. The data looks almost perfectly Gaussian, but try as I might, I can't get a fit better than a certain shape, regardless of the initial guesses I input. I've tried to use the two gaussian equations listed below, but neither fit quite right. Overall I'd like it to be flatter on the continuum (no 'wings') and have a smoother, closer fit to the actual shape if possible.

Due to the nature of the follow-up analysis, the fit **needs** to be a double Gaussian, as I require the fitting parameters, and thus I can't consider other fitting methods. The data can be found here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kMO2ogAL8ZCiDeY29kBvv5lzMfAD7dLj-5rKW8kW9Go/edit?usp=sharing

Below is an example of the code I've been using to try and fit the data, as well as the output figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from lmfit import Model

with open("data.txt","r") as f:
    content=[i.strip() for i in f.readlines()]

vel=[]
I=[]
dI=[]
for i in range(8,len(content)):
    line=content[i].split() 
    vel.append(float(line[0]))
    I.append(float(line[1]))
    dI.append(float(line[2]))

def gaussian(x, A, x0, sig):
        return A*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sig**2))

def gaussian2(x, amp, cen, wid):
        return (amp/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*wid))*np.exp(-(x-cen)**2/(2*wid**2))

def multi_gaussian(x, *pars):
        offset = pars[-1]
        g1 = gaussian(x, pars[1], pars[0], pars[2])
        g2 = gaussian(x, pars[3], pars[0], pars[4])
        return g1 + g2 + offset

def multi_gaussian2(x, *pars):
        offset = pars[-1]
        g1 = gaussian2(x, pars[1], pars[0], pars[2])
        g2 = gaussian2(x, pars[3], pars[0], pars[4])
        return g1 + g2 + offset

offset=1
guess = [-15,-0.01,10,-0.01,10,1]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(multi_gaussian, vel, I, guess)
popt2, pcov2 = curve_fit(multi_gaussian2, vel, I, guess)
x=np.linspace(np.min(vel),np.max(vel), 2000)

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(vel,I,s=0.1,c='b')
plt.plot(x, multi_gaussian(x, *popt), 'r--', linewidth=1,label='Gaussian1')
plt.plot(x, multi_gaussian2(x, *popt2), 'g--', linewidth=1,label='Gaussian2')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image: Gaussian fits to data.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in your linked spreadsheet only has 2 significant digits for velocity and intensity.  That makes it basically impossible to try to "refine" your fit to get a better result.   That said, I highly recommend using a lmfit script like this, that will include your intensity uncertainties in the fit:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from lmfit.models import GaussianModel, ConstantModel

data = np.loadtxt('ddata.txt', skiprows=1)
v = data[:, 0]
i = data[:, 1]
di = data[:, 2]

model = (ConstantModel(prefix='offset_') + 
         GaussianModel(prefix='p1_') + 
         GaussianModel(prefix='p2_'))

params = model.make_params(offset_c=1,
                           p1_amplitude=-1., p1_sigma=100, p1_center=25,
                           p2_amplitude=-1., p2_sigma=100, p2_center=-25)
 
init = model.eval(params, x=v)
result = model.fit(i, params,  weights=1.0/(di+1.e-9), x=v)

print(result.fit_report())
 
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(v, i, s=0.5, label='data')

plt.plot(v, init, label='init')
plt.plot(v, result.best_fit, label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('velocity (mm/s)')
plt.ylabel('intensity')
plt.show()
```

For the data you supplied, this will print out a fit report like this:

```
[[Model]]
    ((Model(constant, prefix='offset_') + Model(gaussian, prefix='p1_')) + Model(gaussian, prefix='p2_'))
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 128
    # data points      = 191
    # variables        = 7
    chi-square         = 654.770994
    reduced chi-square = 3.55853801
    Akaike info crit   = 249.314315
    Bayesian info crit = 272.080229
[[Variables]]
    offset_c:      1.00013943 +/- 5.1045e-05 (0.01%) (init = 1)
    p1_amplitude: -1.36807407 +/- 0.08677931 (6.34%) (init = -1)
    p1_center:     46.8019583 +/- 3.77807981 (8.07%) (init = 25)
    p1_sigma:      57.3859589 +/- 2.39823612 (4.18%) (init = 100)
    p2_amplitude: -1.16999330 +/- 0.08533205 (7.29%) (init = -1)
    p2_center:    -76.1117581 +/- 3.49975073 (4.60%) (init = -25)
    p2_sigma:      51.7080694 +/- 2.08860434 (4.04%) (init = 100)
    p1_fwhm:       135.133604 +/- 5.64741436 (4.18%) == '2.3548200*p1_sigma'
    p1_height:    -0.00951073 +/- 2.6406e-04 (2.78%) == '0.3989423*p1_amplitude/max(2.220446049250313e-16, p1_sigma)'
    p2_fwhm:       121.763196 +/- 4.91828727 (4.04%) == '2.3548200*p2_sigma'
    p2_height:    -0.00902683 +/- 3.5183e-04 (3.90%) == '0.3989423*p2_amplitude/max(2.220446049250313e-16, p2_sigma)'
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(p1_center, p2_amplitude)    = -0.967
    C(p1_amplitude, p2_center)    =  0.959
    C(p1_center, p2_center)       =  0.956
    C(p1_amplitude, p2_amplitude) = -0.946
    C(p1_amplitude, p1_center)    =  0.943
    C(p2_amplitude, p2_center)    = -0.943
```

and a plot of
[image]